# mono - "file does not contain a valid cil image"?

Tags: mono

I have been using a program on my Windows computer for quite some time, but I am using my Ubuntu pc the most these days. Thus, I would like to be able to run this program (.exe file with associated .dll files) on my Ubuntu pc, but I have already given it a try myself using mono, however, this failed. Not sure if this is important, but the program requires the .net framework, which is why I chose to use mono.

I installed mono like this:
[Tutorial on how to install](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin)

The problem is that when I use the command `mono /root/myprogram.exe`, it prints out the error "file does not contain a valid cil image". What can I do?

Comment: I was going through internet searching for this error message and after reading https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/2559 I think that your problem is not Ubuntu related.

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht thanks for your input. I don't get it? How can the binary file (I do not know the source code for this program) have anything to do with a link to the nuget.exe file?

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht I am slightly confused... :(

Comment: And why are you running it from `/root`?

Comment: Please run that from your home folder, and it's not Ubuntu related it's how mono runs you might need to reference certain `dll` files to get it to work see here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9407/Introduction-to-Mono-Your-first-Mono-app

Comment: @George Well, that was just an example. The actual file has the location, "/root/Desktop/Programmer/checkServers.exe".

Comment: Still, it should be run from home folder!

Comment: @George Alright, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @George Update: As expected, it did not change anything regarding this error to move the file to the home folder. Now, I'll try to reference the dll files.

Comment: @George Sadly, references the 3 associated dll files did not change anything either :( Thanks for the input though

Comment: @George Now I just realized that installing only mono-devel is not enough for this. Therefore, I tried installing mono-complete but of course, another error occurred.. I made a new question. Take a look if you know how to fix it, please: https://askubuntu.com/questions/975131/error-when-trying-to-install-mono-complete