# Error when trying to install mono-complete?

Tags: mono

I am trying to install mono-complete after realizing that mono-devel was not enough for my needs. The problem is that whenever I try to install mono-complete, I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-complete : Depends monodoc-manual(= 5.4.1.6 0xarmin1+debian7b1) but it is not going to be install
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can this be fixed?

Output of some commands that I have tried:

```
root@kalik:~# sudo apt-get install mono-complete
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-complete : Depends: monodoc-manual (= 5.4.1.6-0xamarin1+debian7b1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@kalik:~# sudo apt-get remove mono-devel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mono-devel' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  espeak-data finger firebird2.5-common firebird2.5-common-doc gdebi-core
  gnome-packagekit gnome-packagekit-data hwdata imagemagick-common iproute
  libboost-atomic1.61.0 libboost-chrono1.61.0 libboost-date-time1.61.0
  libboost-filesystem1.61.0 libboost-system1.61.0 libboost-thread1.61.0
  libcamel-1.2-57 libchromaprint0 libcrypto++6 libedataserver-1.2-21
  libespeak1 libfftw3-single3 libgeos-3.5.0 libglew1.13 libicu55 liblouis10
  libmimic0 libmono-2.0-dev libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-cecil-private-cil
  libmono-cil-dev libmono-codecontracts4.0-cil
  libmono-compilerservices-symbolwriter4.0-cil libmono-cscompmgd0.0-cil
  libmono-csharp4.0c-cil libmono-custommarshalers4.0-cil libmono-db2-1.0-cil
  libmono-debugger-soft4.0a-cil libmono-http4.0-cil libmono-ldap4.0-cil
  libmono-management4.0-cil libmono-messaging-rabbitmq4.0-cil
  libmono-messaging4.0-cil libmono-microsoft-build-engine4.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-build-framework4.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-build-tasks-v4.0-4.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-build-utilities-v4.0-4.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-build4.0-cil libmono-microsoft-csharp4.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-visualc10.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-web-infrastructure1.0-cil libmono-oracle4.0-cil
  libmono-parallel4.0-cil libmono-peapi4.0a-cil libmono-rabbitmq4.0-cil
  libmono-relaxng4.0-cil libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil libmono-simd4.0-cil
  libmono-smdiagnostics0.0-cil libmono-sqlite4.0-cil
  libmono-system-componentmodel-composition4.0-cil
  libmono-system-componentmodel-dataannotations4.0-cil
  libmono-system-configuration-install4.0-cil
  libmono-system-data-datasetextensions4.0-cil
  libmono-system-data-entity4.0-cil libmono-system-data-linq4.0-cil
  libmono-system-data-services-client4.0-cil
  libmono-system-data-services4.0-cil libmono-system-deployment4.0-cil
  libmono-system-design4.0-cil libmono-system-drawing-design4.0-cil
  libmono-system-dynamic4.0-cil libmono-system-identitymodel-selectors4.0-cil
  libmono-system-identitymodel4.0-cil
  libmono-system-io-compression-filesystem4.0-cil
  libmono-system-io-compression4.0-cil libmono-system-json-microsoft4.0-cil
  libmono-system-json4.0-cil libmono-system-ldap-protocols4.0-cil
  libmono-system-ldap4.0-cil libmono-system-management4.0-cil
  libmono-system-messaging4.0-cil libmono-system-net-http-formatting4.0-cil
  libmono-system-net-http-webrequest4.0-cil libmono-system-net-http4.0-cil
  libmono-system-net4.0-cil libmono-system-numerics-vectors4.0-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-core2.2-cil libmono-system-reactive-debugger2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-experimental2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-interfaces2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-linq2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-observable-aliases0.0-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-platformservices2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-providers2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-runtime-remoting2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-windows-forms2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-windows-threading2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reflection-context4.0-cil
  libmono-system-runtime-caching4.0-cil
  libmono-system-runtime-durableinstancing4.0-cil
  libmono-system-runtime-interopservices-runtimeinformation4.0-cil
  libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil
  libmono-system-servicemodel-activation4.0-cil
  libmono-system-servicemodel-discovery4.0-cil
  libmono-system-servicemodel-internals0.0-cil
  libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil
  libmono-system-servicemodel-web4.0-cil libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil
  libmono-system-serviceprocess4.0-cil
  libmono-system-threading-tasks-dataflow4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-abstractions4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-applicationservices4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-dynamicdata4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-extensions-design4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil libmono-system-web-http-selfhost4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-http-webhost4.0-cil libmono-system-web-http4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-mobile4.0-cil libmono-system-web-mvc3.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-razor2.0-cil libmono-system-web-regularexpressions4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-routing4.0-cil libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-webpages-deployment2.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-webpages-razor2.0-cil libmono-system-web-webpages2.0-cil
  libmono-system-web4.0-cil
  libmono-system-windows-forms-datavisualization4.0a-cil
  libmono-system-windows4.0-cil libmono-system-workflow-activities4.0-cil
  libmono-system-workflow-componentmodel4.0-cil
  libmono-system-workflow-runtime4.0-cil libmono-system-xaml4.0-cil
  libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil libmono-system-xml-serialization4.0-cil
  libmono-tasklets4.0-cil libmono-webmatrix-data4.0-cil
  libmono-windowsbase4.0-cil libmono-xbuild-tasks4.0-cil libmonosgen-2.0-1
  libmonosgen-2.0-dev libnunit-cil-dev libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil
  libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil libnunit-core2.6.3-cil
  libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil libnunit-mocks2.6.3-cil libnunit-util2.6.3-cil
  libopencv-contrib2.4v5 libopencv-legacy2.4v5 libopencv-ml2.4v5 libosinfo-db
  libperl5.22 libpoppler61 libprotobuf9v5 libpython-all-dev
  libqscintilla2-12v5 libqscintilla2-l10n libradare2-0.9.9 libradare2-1.0
  libschroedinger-1.0-0 libvpx3 libwildmidi1 libx265-79 mono-csharp-shell
  mono-mcs mono-roslyn mono-xbuild msbuild msbuild-libhostfxr
  msbuild-sdkresolver python-all python-all-dev python-bson python-bson-ext
  python-clamd python-d2to1 python-defusedxml python-elixir python-gridfs
  python-ipaddr python-keyring python-keyrings.alt python-pip-whl
  python-pycryptopp python-pymongo python-pymongo-ext python-pypdf
  python-secretstorage python-soappy python-stopit python-svn python-wheel
  python-wstools referenceassemblies-pcl rwho rwhod x11-apps xsltproc
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
root@kalik:~# sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
root@kalik:~# sudo apt-get install mono-complete
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-complete : Depends: monodoc-manual (= 5.4.1.6-0xamarin1+debian7b1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@kalik:~# sudo dpkg --configure -a
root@kalik:~# sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
root@kalik:~# sudo apt-get install mono-complete
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-complete : Depends: monodoc-manual (= 5.4.1.6-0xamarin1+debian7b1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@kalik:~# sudo apt-get remove mono-devel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mono-devel' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  espeak-data finger firebird2.5-common firebird2.5-common-doc gdebi-core
  gnome-packagekit gnome-packagekit-data hwdata imagemagick-common iproute
  libboost-atomic1.61.0 libboost-chrono1.61.0 libboost-date-time1.61.0
  libboost-filesystem1.61.0 libboost-system1.61.0 libboost-thread1.61.0
  libcamel-1.2-57 libchromaprint0 libcrypto++6 libedataserver-1.2-21
  libespeak1 libfftw3-single3 libgeos-3.5.0 libglew1.13 libicu55 liblouis10
  libmimic0 libmono-2.0-dev libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-cecil-private-cil
  libmono-cil-dev libmono-codecontracts4.0-cil
  libmono-compilerservices-symbolwriter4.0-cil libmono-cscompmgd0.0-cil
  libmono-csharp4.0c-cil libmono-custommarshalers4.0-cil libmono-db2-1.0-cil
  libmono-debugger-soft4.0a-cil libmono-http4.0-cil libmono-ldap4.0-cil
  libmono-management4.0-cil libmono-messaging-rabbitmq4.0-cil
  libmono-messaging4.0-cil libmono-microsoft-build-engine4.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-build-framework4.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-build-tasks-v4.0-4.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-build-utilities-v4.0-4.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-build4.0-cil libmono-microsoft-csharp4.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-visualc10.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-web-infrastructure1.0-cil libmono-oracle4.0-cil
  libmono-parallel4.0-cil libmono-peapi4.0a-cil libmono-rabbitmq4.0-cil
  libmono-relaxng4.0-cil libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil libmono-simd4.0-cil
  libmono-smdiagnostics0.0-cil libmono-sqlite4.0-cil
  libmono-system-componentmodel-composition4.0-cil
  libmono-system-componentmodel-dataannotations4.0-cil
  libmono-system-configuration-install4.0-cil
  libmono-system-data-datasetextensions4.0-cil
  libmono-system-data-entity4.0-cil libmono-system-data-linq4.0-cil
  libmono-system-data-services-client4.0-cil
  libmono-system-data-services4.0-cil libmono-system-deployment4.0-cil
  libmono-system-design4.0-cil libmono-system-drawing-design4.0-cil
  libmono-system-dynamic4.0-cil libmono-system-identitymodel-selectors4.0-cil
  libmono-system-identitymodel4.0-cil
  libmono-system-io-compression-filesystem4.0-cil
  libmono-system-io-compression4.0-cil libmono-system-json-microsoft4.0-cil
  libmono-system-json4.0-cil libmono-system-ldap-protocols4.0-cil
  libmono-system-ldap4.0-cil libmono-system-management4.0-cil
  libmono-system-messaging4.0-cil libmono-system-net-http-formatting4.0-cil
  libmono-system-net-http-webrequest4.0-cil libmono-system-net-http4.0-cil
  libmono-system-net4.0-cil libmono-system-numerics-vectors4.0-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-core2.2-cil libmono-system-reactive-debugger2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-experimental2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-interfaces2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-linq2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-observable-aliases0.0-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-platformservices2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-providers2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-runtime-remoting2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-windows-forms2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-windows-threading2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reflection-context4.0-cil
  libmono-system-runtime-caching4.0-cil
  libmono-system-runtime-durableinstancing4.0-cil
  libmono-system-runtime-interopservices-runtimeinformation4.0-cil
  libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil
  libmono-system-servicemodel-activation4.0-cil
  libmono-system-servicemodel-discovery4.0-cil
  libmono-system-servicemodel-internals0.0-cil
  libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil
  libmono-system-servicemodel-web4.0-cil libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil
  libmono-system-serviceprocess4.0-cil
  libmono-system-threading-tasks-dataflow4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-abstractions4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-applicationservices4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-dynamicdata4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-extensions-design4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil libmono-system-web-http-selfhost4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-http-webhost4.0-cil libmono-system-web-http4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-mobile4.0-cil libmono-system-web-mvc3.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-razor2.0-cil libmono-system-web-regularexpressions4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-routing4.0-cil libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-webpages-deployment2.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-webpages-razor2.0-cil libmono-system-web-webpages2.0-cil
  libmono-system-web4.0-cil
  libmono-system-windows-forms-datavisualization4.0a-cil
  libmono-system-windows4.0-cil libmono-system-workflow-activities4.0-cil
  libmono-system-workflow-componentmodel4.0-cil
  libmono-system-workflow-runtime4.0-cil libmono-system-xaml4.0-cil
  libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil libmono-system-xml-serialization4.0-cil
  libmono-tasklets4.0-cil libmono-webmatrix-data4.0-cil
  libmono-windowsbase4.0-cil libmono-xbuild-tasks4.0-cil libmonosgen-2.0-1
  libmonosgen-2.0-dev libnunit-cil-dev libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil
  libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil libnunit-core2.6.3-cil
  libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil libnunit-mocks2.6.3-cil libnunit-util2.6.3-cil
  libopencv-contrib2.4v5 libopencv-legacy2.4v5 libopencv-ml2.4v5 libosinfo-db
  libperl5.22 libpoppler61 libprotobuf9v5 libpython-all-dev
  libqscintilla2-12v5 libqscintilla2-l10n libradare2-0.9.9 libradare2-1.0
  libschroedinger-1.0-0 libvpx3 libwildmidi1 libx265-79 mono-csharp-shell
  mono-mcs mono-roslyn mono-xbuild msbuild msbuild-libhostfxr
  msbuild-sdkresolver python-all python-all-dev python-bson python-bson-ext
  python-clamd python-d2to1 python-defusedxml python-elixir python-gridfs
  python-ipaddr python-keyring python-keyrings.alt python-pip-whl
  python-pycryptopp python-pymongo python-pymongo-ext python-pypdf
  python-secretstorage python-soappy python-stopit python-svn python-wheel
  python-wstools referenceassemblies-pcl rwho rwhod x11-apps xsltproc
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
root@kalik:~#
```

Comment: Please run `sudo apt install -f` then `sudo apt update` and try again!

Comment: @George I ran "sudo apt-get install -f", then "sudo apt-get update" and finally "sudo apt-get install mono-complete", which resulted in the same error :( Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do `sudo dpkg --configure -a` then `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @George Same :( oh god

Comment: Please uninstall `mono-devel` then update, then try to install!

Comment: Please run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` one last time!

Comment: @George Did not work either. I have updated my question with all the output from the commands. Please take a look and see if you can come up with any other ideas :)

Comment: Run `'sudo apt autoremove` to remove related files

Comment: @George Did that, then tried to "sudo apt install mono-complete", but this ended in the exact same result. Also tried upgrading afterwards.. I give up. Thanks though!!